# Graphs with maximum and minimum Graph Energies

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, extremal-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

Given a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, if its adjacency matrix $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq . . . \geq \lambda_n$ then the energy is defined as:
$$E(G) =\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\lambda_i|.$$

It was introduced by Gutman in 1978 [I. Gutman, *The energy of a graph*, Ber. Math.-Statist. Sekt. Forschungsz. Graz 103, 1-22 (1978)).
It is related to the total $\pi$-electron energy in a molecule
represented by a (molecular) graph, and currently a very active research field.

Among *trees* with $n$ vertices, the star $S_n$ and the path $P_n$ have minimum and maximum energy, respectively.

> Which graphs with $n$ vertices have minimum and maximum energy in general?

It seems that the complete graph $K_n$ does not have maximum energy.

Comment: Is there a question here? I don't think people know the precise definition of "energy" as it relates to graphs, nor do I think people are going to chase down a reference either [sorry]. It would help if you'd present a precise definition and background.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_energy

Comment: @Mike question is edited accordingly